Patching of openssl for ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I have this testing environment using ubuntu version 20.04 LTS and I wanted to patch all my packages to the latest but found out that there is openssl 1.1.1x but I only can patch my openssl to version 1.1.1f. With some research show that needed ubuntu pro to update it to the latest however requesting for the free ubuntu pro with token attach it still doesnt patch my openssl still stuck at ver 1.1.1f. Is there any way I can patch it to 1.1.1x or there is no other way to do so?

Why do you want to "patch all your packages to the latest"? Ubuntu already have most security patches applied. Also see here.
